# mvc classic sql vs EF

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, performance, entity-framework

Is there anyone who has experience with migrating to EF from classic SQL.

I am familiar with this code:

```
using(MySqlConnection b = new MySqlConnection()) {
    b.ConnectionString = varAccordingToServer.StandardMySQLConnectionString;
    b.Open();
    c.Connection = b;
    c.CommandText = "select count(*) from myTable where condition='1'";
    string t = c.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
}
```

If I start using EF, will there be any performance loss?

Thanks,

Comment: Did you try to measure yourself first?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With great abstractions come great performance losses.

Yes, there might be some performance loss, but in most application it doesn't really matter.
I suggest you try the EF way, and if you prove some part of it hinders performance, optimize this part specifically. EF will probably improve your code and team's velocity enough that you'll have time to worry about performance later.

Comment: Generally, +1. I'm not so sure about 'improving the code and team', you can do hideous things with or without EF, but I value strongly-type queries more than 'stringly typed' SQL for most use cases. When profiling reveals a bottleneck, you can always use raw SQL via EF or use Dapper or other micro-ORM.

Comment: I agree with I3armon; the trick is not to become a slave to EF - there may well be sections within your solution where direct SQL is preferable for many reasons - performance, clarity of solution. ability to modify without deployment...

Comment: .. or even stored procedures. Whatever fits best.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is going to be a performance loss whenever you choose an ORM tool such as EF or NHibernate. The performance loss might be insignificant though. Now, the least of your worries should be performance, the major headache you will see is using a connector that fully supports Entity Framework for MySql...well, I'm assuming your backend database is a MySql database. I still haven't bumped into a connector that doesn't drop support for some features.